# How to write unit test for a Spring AOP class of printing out log?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-aop, powermock, powermockito

I have a Spring AOP class for printing out time consumed log for specific classes like below.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TimeConsumedLog {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeConsumedLog.class);
  @Around("execution(* com.kenshinji..*(..)) and @annotation(com.kenshinji.TimeSpent)")
  public void logConsumedTime(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable{
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Object proceed = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
      MethodSignature msig = (MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
      Object target = thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
      Method currentMethod = target.getClass().getMethod(msig.getName(), msig.getParameterTypes());
      long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
      LOG.debug("" + currentMethod.getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + currentMethod.getName() + " | [ms spent] |" + (end - start));
  }

}
```

Now I need to write unit test for this class. However since the **LOG** field is `private static final`, So I came up with following code to initialize a `TimeConsumedLog`class.

```
TimeConsumedLog timeConsumedLog = new TimeConsumedLog();
Field field = PowerMockito.field(TimeConsumedLog.class, "LOG");
field.set(TimeConsumedLog.class, mock(Logger.class));
```

Because the `LOG` field is mocked and what I need to verify in the unit test is to make sure it log out the specific information I need. So now I'm confused how am I gonna verify this? Am I running into the wrong way for testing the class?

Comment: So you're asking how to verify that a method of a mock has been called? That's what verify() does.

Comment: @JBNizet the **LOG** is `private static final`, how do I pass it to `verify()` method? Thank you.

Comment: You're creating the mock logger in your test: `mock(Logger.class)`. Assign that to a variable, and use `field.set(TimeConsumedLog.class, thatVariable)` and `verify(thatVariable)`.

Comment: @JBNizet my code above is `field.set(TimeConsumedLog.class, mock(Logger.class));`, I can't find a way to assign it to a variable.

Comment: `Logger mockLogger = mock(Logger.class); field.set(TimeConsumedLog.class, mockLogger));`. This is really basic Java/programming stuff. Learn the basics before trying to define and test AOP interceptors. You don't learn how to pilot an Airbus if you don't know what left and right mean yet.

Comment: sorry, my bad and thank you for your anwser @JBNizet